# Infinispan Unique Cache Manager for deployed Web Applications

Tags: java, caching, wildfly, infinispan

I'm working with Infinispan 8.1 and WildFly 10.

I initialize my CacheManager programmatically using these code lines:

```
public class SessionManager {
    private static DefaultCacheManager cacheManager;

    public void initializeCache(){

        if (cacheManager ==null){ 

            GlobalConfigurationBuilder gcbLocal = new GlobalConfigurationBuilder();
            ConfigurationBuilder builderLocal = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builderLocal.clustering().cacheMode(CacheMode.LOCAL);
            cacheManager = new DefaultCacheManager(gcbLocal.build(), builderLocal.build()); 
            cacheManager.getCache();
```

These code lines belong to a jar imported as dependency in multiple web applications deployed on my server.

So every time i deploy a new application, the initialize method is invoked and infinispan tries to create a new DefaultCacheManager, giving me this exception:

```
ISPN000034: There's already a JMX MBean instance type=CacheManager,name="DefaultCacheManager" already registered under 'org.infinispan' JMX domain. If you want to allow multiple instances configured with same JMX domain enable 'allowDuplicateDomains' attribute in 'globalJmxStatistics' config element
```

This issue can be resolved simply adding this code line:

```
gcbLocal.globalJmxStatistics().allowDuplicateDomains(true);
```

But now the effect is that Infinispan will create a new domain separated CacheManager. This means that every application will have its own.

My target is to have just 1 DefaultCacheManager serving all the web applications deployed inside the server the way that if WebApplicationA stores some value inside the infinispan cache, the webApplicationB can get it.

Is it possible? How can i obtain a global Cache Manager?

Answer (score 2):

Ernest is right - MBean servers are per JVM not per ClassLoader, so you need to ignore duplicated domains. But what's more interesting - Wildfly uses Infinispan for session clustering, so the default cache manager might be already running. I strongly recommend using your own cache manager name:

```
new GlobalConfigurationBuilder().globalJmxStatistics()
                    .cacheManagerName(CACHE_NAME).build();
```

Ernest also suggested using a HotRod Server cluster and connecting to it using a HotRod client (which is by far faster than using REST interface). This sounds reasonable in scenario you described.

Comment: Is there the possibility to get cache manager belonging to other web application using jmx infinispan?

Comment: I'm not sure why would you want to use JMX for this? I deeply believe that client/server model is what you need here.

Comment: It s matter of performance. I think that a client server call will take too much time. Being infinispan-jmx aware of duplicated  mbean... It Should give me the possibility to inspect a cachemanager... Or not?

Answer (score 1):

It seems obvious that you're running this code in web modules (.war) -- or in jars bundled in war files. You cannot share instances across web modules as class-loaders are protected (and that's good for you).

You have a few options:

1. Instead of deploying war files, make a single ear file with multiple web modules, and one EJB that will then create and use the cache manager. Each web module will then get to the cache via the local EJB, with infinispan libs deployed in ear/lib.
2. Run Infinispan server (standalone wildfly installation for Infinispan) and change your code to use the remote clients:

   -- HotRod client to connect to it externally (docs here: http://infinispan.org/docs/8.2.x/getting_started/getting_started.html#_using_hot_rod_to_access_an_infinispan_data_grid).

   -- REST client (docs here: http://infinispan.org/docs/8.2.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_infinispan_rest_server)

   Each web module can do this separately.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But you know that infinispan uses jgroups as communication layer over server farm nodes. This way if webapplicationA stores same object into the cache on the ServerNodeA, webapplicationA can get the same object on ServerNodeB. So i was asking... if web modules as class-loaders are protected, why infinispan complains if i have already created a DefaultCacheManager Mbean? Shouldn't the initialization go straight?

Comment: It doesn't really "complain" (remember, there's a config option to change the behaviour, as you mentioned). Further, the instance is checked per VM, not per class loader. There's only one VM on a given Wildfly instance. And regarding your comment about data across nodes, well, that's the point of Infinispan. The question is: why would you want to have to "member" nodes in the same VM (you will have backups of data on the same server instance)? You could do this for testing, but it doesn't really make sense in production.

Comment: ... but imagine to have different web applications as modules of the same ERP having a SSO mechanism. Could be really useful to offer the possibility to share data across the application storing them in a shared cache.

Comment: Different web applications? Yes... But practically, they are different artifacts that are somehow linked to a single higher level application/system (hence the need to share data). In this particular case, the thing to be reviewed is your deployment (IMO). And I don't really think you have a problem as Infinispan does allow for your scenario.